# Search values in multiple CSV files using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

First, I'm really a rare user of Excel. And now, I need to 'develop' with it.

So, basically, I have this form in a workbook (as the first sheet). This form have the folder destination (of which the CSV files are located), the value to search for (say, a unit name), and a button. The folder destination and the value to be searched can be changed according to what the user input in the form.

When the user press the button, the macro will run, and a few of the characteristics of the matching unit in the CSV will be displayed in the next sheet of the workbook.

I have an idea of using the column to search and retrieve the value from the CSV. For example, the value to be searched for all located in the B column of the CSV, while the values need to be retrieve are in C and F respectively.

So, can anyone help me with this? I'm currently doing my research and studies on it since I'm fairly new to this language.

This is what I've done so far. I can get the search function (search, copy, and paste) alright when I tried it on a single workbook. But I could not get the open folder, and loop throught the files. Can anyone help me on this? Any form of help would be much appreciated.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
    Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim filePath
    Dim numOfData
    Dim unitName

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2) 'Set destination worksheet to paste the matching data

    wsDest.Cells.Clear

    'filePath = wsMain.Range("B4").Value 'Get the file path
    unitName = wsMain.Range("B5").Value 'Get the unit name

    'Open the files from the path provided
    strPath = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\DataLog"
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.csv")

    Do While strFile <> vbNullString

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & "\" & strFile)
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)

    noOfData = wsSource.Range("A2:A12").Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row - 1

    'Set row to start to search and copy data to
    LSearchRow = 2
    LCopyToRow = 2

    While Len(wsSource.Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

        'If value in column B = "unitName", copy entire row to Sheet2
        If wsSource.Range("B" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = unitName Then

           'Copy and paste the matching values into the next sheet
           For Count = 2 To noOfData + 1
           wsDest.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Unit No"
           wsDest.Cells(1, 2).Value = unitName
           wsDest.Cells(LCopyToRow, 1).Value = _
           wsSource.Cells(LSearchRow, 3).Value
           wsDest.Cells(LCopyToRow, 2).Value = _
           wsSource.Cells(LSearchRow, 6).Value
           Next Count

           'Move counter to next row
           LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

           'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
           wsSource.Select

         End If

            LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

    Wend

    wbSource.Close True
    strFile = Dir()

    Loop



    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

    Exit Sub

    Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred."

    End Sub
```

Comment: You could throw me an email with your file and I will see what I can do for you

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the response! I highly appreciate it.